# Paragraph inside enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, paragraphs

I want to write a paragraph inside an enumerate. My code is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, listparindent=0.7cm]
\item Example

Example example example example example example example example example
example example example example example example example example example example
example example example example example example example example example example
example example.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

and it produces this:
[image]

I would like to set the paragraph's alingment to the same point where 1 is without ending the enumerate. I want it to look like this:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[
leftmargin=0pt, itemindent=20pt,
labelwidth=15pt, labelsep=5pt, listparindent=0.7cm,
align=left]
\item Example

Example example example example example example example example example
example example example example example example example example example example
example example example example example example example example example example
example example.


Example example example example example example example example example
example example example example example example example example example example
example example example example example example example example example example
example example.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's simpler using the `wide=` key. Note that, by default, `listparindent` is set to 0pt because there is a non-zero `parsep`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} \usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, listparindent=1.25em, parsep=0pt]
\item Example

Example example example example example example example example example
example example example example example example example example example example
example example example example example example example example example example
example example.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]